# Prevent stack from recompiling external dependencies

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am relatively new to stack and haskell. Before I explain my question, let me explain our development setup. We use **jenkins** to build our repo. The haskell project will be a small subset of a larger python project. The haskell project is mainly used to generate artifacts.

The jenkins master does a `git clean` each time before building a git branch. My haskell project has some external dependency like `argparser` & `aeson`. Each time my build scripts execute a `stack build`, these external dependencies get compiled because they are deleted when jenkins executes the git clean command.

Is there anyway to tell stack to download the external deps to a global folder outside the project folder? Like the `global-pkg-db` path instead of the `.stack-work` folder? What is the best way to prevent stack to not recompile the external dependencies?

Should I download `argparser` & `aeson` into a custom folder and pass that path into `extra-lib-dirs`?

```
# This file was automatically generated by stack init
# For more information, see: http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/

# Specifies the GHC version and set of packages available (e.g., lts-3.5, nightly-2015-09-21, ghc-7.10.2)
resolver: lts-5.8

# Local packages, usually specified by relative directory name
packages:
- '.'
# Packages to be pulled from upstream that are not in the resolver (e.g., acme-missiles-0.3)
extra-deps:
- aeson-0.11.1.1
- argparser-0.3.4
- text-1.2.2.0

# Override default flag values for local packages and extra-deps
flags: {}

# Extra package databases containing global packages
extra-package-dbs: []
```

Comment: Could you just do a `git clean -e .stack-work` in the Jenkins job instead of `git clean`?

Comment: You can also run `stack install aeson and whatever` outside of the project dir, and stack would install it globally and then use it. But it would need to copy binaries into `.stack-work` every time, so `git clean -e` is better solution.

Comment: I did a `stack install argparser-0.3.4` & `stack install argparser` and it doesn't install argparser. I was able to do `stack unpack argparser-0.3.4` then cd into the folder and do `stack init` & `stack build`.

Comment: @arrowd's suggestion should work if the package is installed globally with the same resolver as your project. So, the right incantation would be something like `stack --resolver lts-5.12 build argparse` if your project uses `lts-5.12`. Feel free to open an issue at https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack if that doesn't work for you or to suggest a feature.